# require module located in subdirectory

Tags: lua

I have a directory that looks as follows:

```
Test
|
|---src
|    |
|    |---main
|    |    |
|    |    |---main.lua
|
|---libraries
|       |
|       |---testlibraries.lua
```

I need to import `testlibraries.lua` in my `main.lua` file. I already tried things like `require "../../libraries/testlibraries"` and havent found a solution using the stackoverflow search.

Comment: `dofile` lets you provide a full path.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
package.path = package.path .. ';../../libraries/testlibraries.lua;'
```